# Referencing a Calendar in multiple sites, Adding a column, then hiding it

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, sharepoint-calendar

What I'm trying to accomplish is referencing a calendar on every site designated, adding a named text column to that calendar, then hiding that created column from the New and Edit form. I think I'm just about there but I'm not great with PowerShell so I think I've got some pieces mixed up.

Edit: An additional part to this would be great if I could include the Calendar on the default page "home.aspx".

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") 
$siteNumbers = "03", "14", "22035", "22036", "22040", "22041", "22042", "22043", "22044", "2210", "31"

Foreach($wnl in $siteNumbers)
    {
    $rootWeb = (Get-SPWeb ("http://site/path/" + $wnl))

#Get an reference to the  calendar
$calendarlist=$rootWeb.Lists["Calendar"]                           
#Get a reference to a text field 
$fieldtype=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text                 
#Add a new test text field to the calendar 
$calendarlist.Fields.Add("GCID", $fieldtype, $false)  
#Get a reference to the created field
$CalField = $calendarlist.Fields["GCID"]
#Hide the column in New and Edit Mode
$CalField.ShowInEditForm = $false
$CalField.ShowInNewForm = $false        
#Push Update
$CalField.Update()
$calendarlist.Update()
```

The above code referenced the calendar on each site added the column "GCID" but it did not hide it. Do I need to create the column, do the list.update, then hide the column from new/edit, then do the column.update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should perform an independent field update as the following

- The below line will actually add the column to the list

  ```
   $calendarlist.Fields.Add("GCID", $fieldtype, $false)
  ```
- Then run the below cmdled to update the list, no need to perform `$CalField.Update()`

  ```
  $calendarlist.Update()
  ```
- Then Get your field again

  ```
  $CalField = $calendarlist.Fields["GCID"]
  ```
- Then perform your Hide setting

  ```
  $CalField.ShowInEditForm = $false
  $CalField.ShowInNewForm = $false
  ```
- Then update your column field

  ```
  $CalField.Update()
  ```
- Optionally you can run list update again.

  ```
  $calendarlist.Update()
  ```

---

**The Final script should look like**

```
$rootWeb = Get-SPWeb http://your site
#Get an reference to the  calendar
$calendarlist=$rootWeb.Lists["your list"]                           
#Get a reference to a text field 
$fieldtype=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text                 
#Add a new test text field to the calendar 
$calendarlist.Fields.Add("GCID", $fieldtype, $false)  
#Push list Update
$calendarlist.Update() 
#Get a reference to the created field
$CalField = $calendarlist.Fields["GCID"]
#Hide the column in New and Edit Mode
$CalField.ShowInEditForm = $false
$CalField.ShowInNewForm = $false        
#Push field Update
$CalField.Update()
```

Comment: OK, so my issue was I had the `$calendarlist.Update()` out of order. Thanks for the help! Marked as answer.